# Loop through worksheets and create tables

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 worksheets.

I want to create a table for each. every table has a different amount of data, ive been using the following code for each, but i was wondering how to do it with a loop.

I would truly apreciate some help :)

```
Sub table()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("m9")
    Set StartCell = Range("A1")

    lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(lastrow, LastColumn)).Select

    Dim objTable As ListObject
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
End Sub
```

Tried the following, but with no luck

```
    Sub loop_test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_num As Integer

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet
ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To ws_num
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
    '
    Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Set StartCell = Range("A1")


  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  Range(StartCell, Cells(lastrow, LastColumn)).Select

  Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)



Next

starting_ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If you are wondering how to do it with a loop then look up looping and try some examples.

Comment: I have been looking for about two hours and trying different example, but i cant get it to work. This is why i tried asking a question.

Comment: You are almost there. Presuming that your UDF does what you want for individual sheets, have a incoming parameter for `Worksheet`. You can then call this UDF from a master UDF that that holds a pointer to all sheets you want updated (i.e. maybe in an array). Then call this UDF passing the `Sheet` as a `Worksheet` object. should do the trick. Alos, Have a look at why we shouldn't use `Select` and `Activate` in VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `Activate` and `Select` statements. The following will loop through all worksheets in the workbook and add a `ListObject` to each sheet. It will also test to see whether there is an already existing `ListObject`. If the existing `ListObject` overlaps with the range that you're going to add the table into to, it will convert it to a range before recreating the `ListObject`

```
Sub loop_test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StartCell As Range, TblRng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim objTable As ListObject

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set objTable = Nothing
        With ws
            Set StartCell = .Range("A1")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            LastColumn = .Cells(StartCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


            Set TblRng = .Range(StartCell, .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
            ' Test if table exists on sheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objTable = .ListObjects(1)
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' If table overlaps with TblRng - Convert to Range
            If Not Intersect(objTable.Range, TblRng) Is Nothing Then
                objTable.Unlist
            End If
            ' Create Table
            Set objTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TblRng, , xlYes)
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That’s great. If it answered your question don’t forget to accept the answer by clicking on the tick to the left of it / upvoting it

Answer (score 0):

Try this. As Zac says, steer clear of activating and selecting and include sheet references.

```
Sub loop_test()

Dim i As Long 'use Long, integer only goes up to c32k
Dim ws_num As Long

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

ws_num = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range, r As Range
Dim objTable As ListObject

For i = 1 To ws_num
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i) 'don't need to activate
        Set StartCell = .Range("A1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = .Range(StartCell, .Cells(lastrow, LastColumn))
        Set objTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, r, , xlYes)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```